# How to save values in Powershell array

Tags: powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I have a below code. I can't save backupmodules details for all the pool in Pools file in variable b.
When I am generating output of variable b, it is giving me the output for only last pool in pools.
Is there any way (like arrays), which can be used to save backupmodule details for all the pool in pools in variable b?
Please help!!

```
$pools= Get-Content -Path "F:\Scripts\Pools.txt"
foreach ($pool in $pools){
$a = get-csbackupservicestatus -poolfqdn "$pool"
$b=$a.backupModules
$x= $pool
}
$b
```

Comment: show your `$a`'s content

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample code for you -

```
# An array to store data
$outArr = @()
# Append into arry
$outArr += "abcd"
$outArr += "xyz"
# Print an array
write-host $outArr
```

In your case, you need to ***declare*** your array **`$b`** first & then you can append into it; So, your code will look something like this -

```
$b = @()
$pools = Get-Content -Path "F:\Scripts\Pools.txt"
foreach ($pool in $pools) {
    $a = get-csbackupservicestatus -poolfqdn "$pool"
    $b += $a.backupModules
}
Write-Host $b
```